# GASでClassroomApp.でのメソッドが機能しない？

Tags: google-apps-script

Google Classroomで新しいクラスの生成をするスクリプトを記述していて、
const ClassroomApp = Utilities.getGAService("classroom");
と宣言したところで、デバッグが止まってしまいます。

変数
local

ClassroomApp: undefined

ライブラリの追加は、Utilitiesの場合は設定不要だと理解しておりますし、スコープの選定は確認済みです。
どこを改善すればいいでしょう？